# Expressionengine concat inside if

Tags: parsing, templates, expressionengine

What is the proper way to cocatenate strings inside *if* statement?
For ex.:
    {if {site_url}{segment_1} == page_url} class="selected" {/if }

I need to concatenate *site_url* and *segment_1* then compare it to *page_url*.

Answer (score 0):

On Expressionegine conditionals you can use

```
{if {var} == ''} or {if "{var}" == ''}
```

Maybe it work

```
{if "{site_url}{segment_1}" == "page_url"} class="selected" {/if }
```